# Cloning Open Cart admin language issue

Tags: opencart, language-packs

I'm trying to clone one **fully functioning opencart website** to another. The front-end of the website is in Dutch and the back-end I have left English default.

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Copy database to new environment
2. Copy files and edit both the config files(config.php and admin/config.php) to match the server paths.

when i go to test the site, all seems to be working fine, until i go to the admin section where i find this blasted error which seems to be very common:

```
Notice: Error: Could not load language dutch! in /opt/www/prezent/graviolashop.de/HTML/system/library/language.php on line 39
```

I'm not sure if this is a path issue or something wrong with the db?

I have googled this issue but none are specific to my perticular case. Has anyone had this issue and resolved it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's unable to load the language and you've copied them over as you say, then this is going to be a config issue. Ensure your path is exactly as it should be. A good way to do this is to create a file such as `error.php` in your root website folder. Then put some erroneous code in it like

```
<?php
dfs sdf sd;
```

Then call the file at `www.yoursite.com/error.php`, and it will show you the path in the error which you can copy exactly. One other unlikely but possible problem could be permissions, but the former is far more likely

Comment: :-) Instead of this `dfs sdf sd;` I am using **`echo getcwd();`** which prints the current working directory's absolute path... BTW, the path is also outputted in the error message the OP has provided: `/opt/www/prezent/graviolashop.de/HTML/`.

Comment: thanks guys, it was indeed a config issue, i had this define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/HTML/admin'); i changed it to define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/opt/www/prezent/graviolashop.de/HTML/admin/'); and it worked.